# Should I avoid using the C# "is" operator for equality checks?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

A colleague told me I could use `is` and `is not` instead of the equality operators `==` and `!=`. I thought the `is` operator had something to do with types, and [the official docs on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) agrees, but it also states:

> Beginning with C# 7.0, you can also use the is operator to match an expression against a pattern

I didn't think checking values with `is` would work, but strangely it does:

```cs
> "tomato" is "apple"
false
> 1 is not 2
true
```

I assume it is the "expression pattern matching" at work here(?). My question is, since using `is` as the equality operator (`==`) seemingly works for values as well, is there any reason to avoid it? Would it be fine, performance and readability wise, to use `is` for all equality checks?

Comment: While `"tomato" is "apple"` works, `oneStringVariable is otherStringVariable` won't. The argument after `is` needs to be a constant or a type. For that reason you'd end up writing `oneStringVariable is "apple"` but `oneStringVariable == otherStringVariable`. I think this question might be opinion-based (readability), but it has received 3 upvotes so I might be wrong and won't vote to close it. For consistency, it seems like you should use `==`.

Comment: Note that the second operand must be a constant. For example, `s1 is s2` is not legal if `s2` is a variable. So, it can't completely replace `==`. (Just an FYI).

Comment: Another side note: `is null` is recommended over `== null`. I would stick with `==` for other equality checks though.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Llama! I didn't realize the right hand side had to be a constant, that explains it! I will stick to `==` for all equality comparisons unless I need the features of the `is` operator.

Comment: Adding to `is null` being recommended over `== null`, this recommendation is related, at least in part, to the fact that objects can have their `Equals` method overridden.

Answer (score 3):

With the exception of `x is null` they are the same and a matter of taste for constant values. As in described in the comments, pattern matching only works for constants. The special case of checking for null guarantees to not use any overloaded equality operator. I cross-checked that with ILSpy:

Original source code:

```cs
string tomatoString = "tomato";
object tomatoObj = "tomato";
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString.Equals("tomato"));
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString is "tomato");
Console.WriteLine(tomatoObj is "tomato");
Console.WriteLine("tomato" is "tomato");
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString is null);
```

Decompiled with ILSpy:

```cs
string tomatoString = "tomato";
object tomatoObj = "tomato";
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString.Equals("tomato"));
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString == "tomato");
string text = tomatoObj as string;
Console.WriteLine(text != null && text == "tomato");
Console.WriteLine(value: true);
Console.WriteLine(tomatoString == null);
```

(For Completness: Note that if you test it with literals on both sides, the compiler will just replace it with its constant result. Note that the static type will introduce necessary null checks)